# Why does my marketing URL redirect me to the site root?

Tags: multilingual, urls

[Question transposed from Slack]
We are trying to create a site with a virtualFolder of `/chr`.  When we navigate to home page in the site, the system redirects us back to the site root. We have checked aliases, mod_rewrite/helicon ape/urlRewrite, and ignoreUrlPrefixes and all that stuff to no avail.

We have noticed the following works with no issue:

- /ch-r
- /chr1
- /chs

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Props to @rosscartwright, @cassidydotdk, and @jammykam for getting us to the answer at lightning speed and for the helpful links.*

The issue was a feature of Sitecore called `AlwaysStripLanguage` that is controlled by a Sitecore Setting in the `Language` group that controls the activation of a processor in the `<preprocessRequest />` pipeline called `Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage`.

Turns out that this component will not only remove URL prefixes it recognises as a language registered on the site (in /sitecore/system/Languages), but it will respond to any code that maps to a culture known to Windows.

For a list of the known culture codes check this [ISO 639-2 Language Code List](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) - you will notice that in our case the issue was the Cherokee language.

There is also an article on [Sitecore Community - Prevent the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS from Interpreting URL Path Prefixes as Language Names](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/prevent-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms-from-interpreting-url-path-prefixes-as-language-names) that is a port of an old article by @JohnWest.

In our case we have replaced the default processor with a new one that only removes a language if it is configured in the list of languages for the site.  Note that as it states in John's article, these processors run **before** there is a site context as the Site Resolver is in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline that runs later.  Mileage will vary - build yourself a solution that suits your use case.

I will upload our solution to the [Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net) in due course so if you're looking for it, have a poke around in there.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this in here :-)  You are welcome to mark your own answer as valid - this is encouraged behaviour in this case.

Comment: @MarkCassidy - SO makes me wait 2 days to mark my own answer; but feel free (might be because I only have 150 rep in this new site)

Comment: All good :-)  I can't mark it - only you can :-)